# Limits of a monotone function

Tags: real-analysis

Let f:  $\Bbb R \mapsto \Bbb R $ be a continuous function, we know that f is strictly decreasing. Can we directly say that $\lim_{x\to\infty} f = -\infty$ ?

Comment: No. Just take $f(x):=e^{-x}$. Or do you mean that $\Bbb R$ is the image of $f$?

Comment: thank you, no I didn't mean that R is the image

Answer (score 0):

If $f(\mathbb R)=\mathbb R$, then yes. Otherwise, now, there are many functions that are strictly decreasing and have a lower bound. Simple examples would be $f(x)=e^{-x}$, or $f(x)=-\arctan(x)$

Comment: thanks for your time